# Is there a way to determine rather my object method is a function or not

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I have a function that iterates through an array of objects and returns a template literal that grabs a property value (name) and also a property value that is a function method (this is .move / how many steps they will take) The .move method uses math.random to pick a random number of steps and return that value. However, in some objects the move property is defined as an integer such as 1 or 2 instead of a random number.

Is there a way to change my `fitnessTest` function so that it will accept both the `.move()` and `.move`?

I tried using an if else statement inside of my while statement saying

```js
while (steps <= 20) {
  if (typeof arrayObject == function) {
    steps += arrayObject[i].move();
    turns++;
  } else
    steps += arrayObject[i].move;
    turns++;
```

which returns the objects who have .move values defined as integers correctly but then doesnt return random numbers for the objects who have .move().

```
function fitnessTest(arrayObject){
  let turnsArray = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arrayObject.length; i++){
    let steps = 0;
    let turns = 0;
    while (steps <= 20){
      steps += arrayObject[i].move();
      turns++;
    } turnsArray.push(`${arrayObject[i].name} took ${turns} turns to take 20 steps.` );
  }      return turnsArray;
}
```

Right now, the function will iterate through an array of objects who have `.move()` as a function that generates a random number and return the proper string, but the objects who have .move set as an integer it will just give me a

> type error of `arrayObject[i].move` is not a function

Comment: `typeof arrayObject == function` should be `typeof arrayObject[i].move == function`

Comment: `typeof arrayObject` will give you the type of `arrayObject` ... `arrayObject[i].move` is not the same type as `arrayObject` obviously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.`typeof` returns a string value, you need to compare against a string of JavaScript types.

2.
You should test if the property `move` of a single item of `arrayObject` is a function, not `arrayObject` itself:

`typeof arrayObject[i].move == 'function'`

Comment: This should be a comment. Please wait till you have enough privilege to comment

Answer (score 0):

Check `typeof` array element but not the array variable.

```
var arr = [ { move: 10}, {move: function () {}} ];
console.log(typeof arr) // object
console.log(typeof arr[0].move) // number
console.log(typeof arr[1].move) // function
```

Change your code to :

```
while (steps <= 20) {
  if (typeof arrayObject[i].move === "function") {
    steps += arrayObject[i].move();
    turns++;
  } else   if (typeof arrayObject[i].move === "number")
    steps += arrayObject[i].move;
    turns++
```

Answer (score 0):

`typeof` gives you a string, so you need to equate it with a string using `""`. Also compare the `move` property and not the object itself.

You can use ternary operator for your purpose and can have a more elegant code.

```
while (steps <= 20) {
  steps += typeof arrayObject[i].move === "function" ? arrayObject[i].move() : arrayObject[i].move;
  turns++;
}
```